# Related products listing : Joomla with VirtueMart 2.6.14

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am new to Joomla and VirtueMart. I am stuck in the "related products" listing section. As the related products can be added manually from the VirtueMart Admin panel, I want to give some filter or condition for these products when displaying in the frontend (like a product should not be displayed when it is sold out etc). Please someone suggest me a way out or tell me the files which fulfill my need. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Checking files of VM version 2.6.14 the view file for related products is under: `components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default_relatedproducts.php`.

The display code is the:

```
if(!empty($field->display)) {
    ?><div class="product-field product-field-type-<?php echo $field->field_type ?>">
            <span class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php }
}
```

The adjustment that you have to do to check for product stock is the:

```
$productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');
$this_product = $productModel->getProduct($field->customfield_value, true, false);
if(!empty($field->display) && !empty($this_product->product_in_stock)) {
    ?><div class="product-field product-field-type-<?php echo $field->field_type ?>">
            <span class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php }
}
```

Please remember to create a template override to be sure that it won't be overriden on future updates. You should place the modified file under: `templates/*your_template/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default_relatedproducts.php`.

---

**As for Virtuemart 3** related products merged in customfields template and could located under: `components/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/customfields.php`.

So this part should be adjusted:

```
if (!empty($field->display)){
    ?><div class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></div><?php
}
```

To:

```
if($field->field_type == "R"){
    $productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');
    $this_product = $productModel->getProduct($field->customfield_value, true, false);
    if (!empty($field->display) && !empty($this_product->product_in_stock)){
        ?><div class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></div><?php
    }
} elseif (!empty($field->display)){
    ?><div class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></div><?php
}
```

In this case overriden file has to be placed under: `templates/*your_template/html/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/customfields.php`.